# Unit test not accepting new parameter type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm still really new to TypeScript so if I'm missing something obvious please let me know!!!

I'm having a problem with debugging my unit test and am stumped. I added a new type for my option label; it used to accept just string but I added `ReactElement` as well so it can accept formatted content through `ReactMarkdown`. My application runs just fine with this update but my unit tests are throwing the following error:

```
Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.
Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

I'm not sure exactly what to do. I suppose I could add something to RadioButtonGroupProps to handle .props but I'm not sure what to add and where.

Here's where I'm calling `preparerOptions` in my unit test.

[image: .label works in my form but not in my test.]

My definition for `preparerOptions`.

[image: definition for preparerOptions]

Defining what types are legal for the label prop.

[image: interface for options declaring what types are allowed]

Comment: Don't post pictures of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Props could be either string or ReactElement, so you need to either

1. Handle both cases - by checking whether in this case it's string or ReactElement (typeof, instanceof), and then repeating step 2 for both of them, or
2. Handle single case - cast the label as one of the types to tell typescript compiler that you know what you're doing and it shouldn't get in the way

   ```
   (results[0].label as ReactElement).props.source // or
   (<ReactElement> results[0].label).props.source
   ```

[Learn the difference between <> and as](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion)